# Having a varying character in a regex with 2 options

Tags: regex, go

I use regex to define a URL using [gorilla mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux):

```
/v2/operations/{operation:(?:ACC00000)\\d+}/meters
```

This URL initially had to match `ACC00000xxx` where xxx is an integer. This regex is working. ( for `ACC00000354` for instance)

Now the third character can also be a `I`. I tried replacing it with `?`, or changing it with `[C|I]` but I can't make it match with the two options:

- `ACC00000123`
- `ACI00000234`

Any idea why is it failing?

Comment: How about `[CI]` instead of `[C|I]`?

Answer (score 3):

You need this

```
AC[CI]00000\d+
```

"?" denotes that the character is present one or zero times. ? does NOT mean any character. "[CI]" means of of two characters C or I should match.  Any character is denoted by a dot ".". This would also work

```
AC.00000\d+
```

https://regex101.com/r/UKHGFo/1

https://regex101.com/r/UKHGFo/2

Answer (score -1):

`[C|I]` this mean to match **C** or **|** or **I**

You should use `(?:C|I)` or `(?:(?:ACC|ACI)00000))`